# To schedule something, is it "schedule in" or "schedule on?"

Tags: prepositions

For example,

Ryan **scheduled** Twitter posts for his shoe business **on** Hootsuite, a social media management platform.

Ryan **scheduled** Twitter posts for his shoe business **in** Hootsuite, a social media management platform.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I have got this right. Hootsuite is a tool that you can use to automatically post things on Twitter at a specified time.  If so, I would have thought **using** was the best way to describe this.

If Hootsuite is an application like Outlook that runs on your computer, you could also use **in**. Here is an example:

> How to Schedule an Outgoing Email **in** Outlook

The preposition **on** is appropriate for the actual posting - "post **on** twitter", like pinning a notice **on** a notice board. It might also be appropriate for scheduling a post if Hootsuite is a web site.

Comment: I'd argue "on" would be valid if Hootsuite is a website, as in "scheduled it on Hootsuite [dot com]". Otherwise I agree.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you fair comment. I have updated my answer.